# My laptop has no operating system is it possible to download Ubuntu into my phone and transfer it to my laptop?

Tags: laptop

my laptop has no operating system can I download Ubuntu using my phone and transferring to my laptop is that possible? without an operating system I cannot use my laptop to log on to the Internet I need an operating system for that so can someone help me please

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and assume you're talking about Ubuntu - question edited to reflect that.

Comment: Do you have a friend who can download and burn install media for you? Also look for a linux user group in your area. Or use the phone to order pre-made installation media from Canonical or one of the companies that advertise at distrowatch. These are usually around $5 USD, if that's possible for you. If the phone is Android, it might be possible to install a terminal app that might let you download an iso, then use dd to burn it to a mounted usb. There are several Android apps that let you install linux tools.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an Android phone, there is an app on the Google Play Store called [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en) that claims you can use your phone as a live USB and allows you to boot your PC from ISO/IMG files stored on your phone. This application requires root. I have no personal experience with this, but it could be worth a shot.

[image]